# When I finish installing from my custom profile, it says "drupal already installed". Clues?

Tags: drupal, drupal-distributions

More precisely, I am facing this issue while trying to install https://github.com/barraponto/thacker-profile (commit 75c693581796eddae5fc39870dfcc2647e00c81b shows the bug, I will update if i can fix it).

Comment: Check that your settings.php point to empty database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that if the sitename variable is already defined, drupal halts its installation.